# How to represent this two level deep relationship in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-admin, django-admin-filters

The scenario is like this,

I have three models :

```
Category, Subcategory and Posts
```

and reltionship among them is like this.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.cat

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    cat=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    subcat=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.subcat

class Posts(models.Model):
     title=models.CharField(max_length=15)
     subcat=models.ForeignKey(Subcategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
     def __str__(self): 
         return self.title
```

Everything is fine. I have added categories from admin panel and added and linked subcategories with categories too. I, however, want to add posts from admin panel too. Now, the problem is when I'm adding a post from admin panel and selecting subcategories, it lists all the subcategories from all the categories( which is obvious as I have subcategory field in post model). I don't want this behavior, I want to get subcategories from only certain category while saving.

For eg: I have a category Django and its subcategories ORM, VIEWS. Plus I have additional subcategories from other categories, say C++. So, If I am publishing a Post and I want that to come from Django category, it should only list ORM and VIEWS in the suggestion in the admin panel.

I'm open to make modification in models, like if an additional field is required or something similar like that. Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How are you choosing the category from which each post entry would gather subcategeries to select? The `Posts` model doesn't have a field relating to a `Category`.

If the logic for chosing a caterory is extern to each `Posts` entry, you could use this snippet for achieving this (from [here](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filter_fk_dropdown.html))

```
@admin.register(Posts)
class PostsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # (...)
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "subcat":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Subcategory.objects.filter(cat__cat=['Django'])
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

However (and maybe this is what you are really trying to get), if you want each post to have its subcategory filtered by a it's specific category, you could first add a category field on its model:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    cat=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    subcat=models.ForeignKey(Subcategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

Then, you could filter que queryset using a custom Form (from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)):

```
class PostsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # use the following for python 2 instead
        # super(PostsAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['subcat'].queryset = Subcategory.objects.filter(
            cat__id=self.instance.cat.id)

@admin.register(Posts)
class PostsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # (...)
    form = PostsAdminForm
```

Comment: Your second solution seems absolutely what I need. I checked docs and the second code snippet you mentioned is what I need. However it is giving me error,'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'. It shouldn't give the error. Would you mind looking the code and let me know why is it giving the error

Comment: Hi again, It looks like there is some minor error in the code. 
First thing, I think, cat__id==self.instance.cat.id should be cat__id=self.instance.cat.id. And second thing, self.instance.cat.id doesn't seem to work as self.instance is giving "Title" as output on printing, which is my default value for title field. Just one thing and my thing is done. Can you tell me how do I get selected 'cat' option from admin form in my __init__ in PostsAdminForm ? self.fields['cat'] gives multiplechoice field and not the selected value from the PostAdminForm.